# Failed to fetch: copying .runtimeconfig.json to /workspace/.runtimeconfig.json: zip: not a valid zip file Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Recently when I tried to bump the Node Js version of my firebase functions, an error started to pop up while pushing the code to Firebase. It is the following error:

> Build failed: failed to Fetch: copying .runtimeconfig.json to /workspace/.runtimeconfig.json: zip: not a valid zip file

This error is not solely related to one function, it shows up for every function that I try to push to Firebase.

My function looks like the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

var serviceAccount = {
};

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

app.get('/test', cors(corsOptions), async function (req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).send({ message: "Hello world!" });
});

const statistics = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = {
  statistics,
};
```

I tried running "firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json" in the functions directory and updating firebase-functions

Comment: Are you using cmd or PowerShell to run that runtime config command?

Comment: @samthecodingman I tried both, there was no difference between the two.